# Error while running GitHub action android

Tags: android, kotlin, continuous-integration, github-actions

GitHub  action build failed with the below exception

```
> Task :app:spotlessKotlinCheck FAILED
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:spotlessKotlinCheck'.

> The following files had format violations:
> app/src/androidTest/java/com/example/androiddevchallenge/ExampleInstrumentedTest.kt

While I running this locally

```
./gradlew :app:spotlessKotlinCheck
```

It shows build success.

How to fix this?

Comment: I have also faced so many GitHub action fails when submitting the Android Dev Challenge. What I did. Formated code + Add Licence in every file and explicitly import all classes instead of using all (*).

Comment: How you format code?

Comment: @Muhammad Farhan ,I also removed all wild card entry (*),and all the file contains licence comment in the top,but the build failed

Comment: It seems it says that your class ```ExampleInstrumentedTest.kt``` has some formated issues. did you put the *Copyright 2021 License*? and run ```spotlessKotlinApply```  task.

Comment: One more thing don't change the MainActivity directory.

Comment: i don't even touch the ExampleInstrumentedTest.kt fiile,yes it has a license, and run spotlessKotlinApply ,also I didn't even change the directory of MainActivity

Comment: you can check my repo https://github.com/dfeverx/countdown-timer

Comment: I'm also confused as I am using spotless for the first time too. But I saw one thing and that might be the cause is that in **app -> src** directory you have only **androidTest and main** directory, the only **test** directory is missing in there.

Comment: in the **src** directory, you have only two (2) **sub directories** and it normally has three (3) directories which are **androidTest, main, & test**

Comment: https://github.com/dfeverx/tick-tick-counter this repo contains the test directory ,it also throw the same error

Comment: I'm sorry didn't help you out. But I think I have found the solution now. recently it gives me the same formatted error in ```MainActivity.kt``` and fail. I did run these **Gradle Tasks** *1.* ```spotlessKotlin```, *2.* ```spotlessKotlinApply```, & *3.* ```spotlessKotlinCheck``` and then Commit and Push the code and it works out for me.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but these Gradle commands didn't work for me  ./gradlew spotlessKotlin ,
./gradlew spotlessKotlinApply and ./gradlew spotlessKotlinCheck